# How do I break the string in output into 2 parts in this assembly code

Tags: assembly, output, sequence, masm, irvine32

So I want to break the break "The nth term in Fibonacci Series is " string into two:

"The " and "th term in Fibonacci Series is ", print the first string, then print the value of n (say using WriteInt), then print the second string.

But I can't seem to get the right output, any tips on how to break them into two?

This is my output now (let's say I entered 4 as input):

```
Display Fibonacci Series
Enter number of fibonacci series terms: 4
Fibonacci Series is
0
1
1
2
Sum of Fibnoacci Series = 4
Press any key to continue...
```

How can I change it to this input that I want:

```
Display Fibonacci Series
Enter the number in fibonacci sequence number: 4
The 4th sequence in Fibonacci Series is
2
Press any key to continue...
```

Also right now the formula in this code is fibonacci, how do I change it to new formula like this;

```
f(n-2)/2 + f(n-1) * 2
```

This is my code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
; insert variables here
  dPrevious DWORD 0   
    dCurrent  DWORD 1   
    dNext DWORD 1     
    dNumberOfTerms DWORD 0
    dSum DWORD 0
    msg1 BYTE "Enter the Fibonacci sequence number : ",0 ; A null-terminated string
    msg2a BYTE "The ", 0
    msg2b BYTE "th term in Fibonacci Series is ", 0
    msg3 BYTE "th term in Fibonacci Series is ", WriteString
    msg4 BYTE "Error: Fibonacci Series must have at least 2 numbers",0



 .CODE
; insert all executable statements here
main PROC
    mov edx, OFFSET msgFibonacciSeries  ; "Display Fibonacci Series and Sum of Fibonacci Series in Assembly Language "
    call WriteString                    ; Display a null-terminated string.
    call Crlf                           ; Writes an end-of-line sequence to the console window.

    mov edx, OFFSET msg1      ; "Enter Number of Fibonacci Series Terms : "
    call WriteString          ; Display a null-terminated string.
    call ReadInt              ; Input a 32-bit signed decimal integer
                              ; from the keyboard and save in EAX.
  mov dNumberOfTerms, eax

    mov ebx,dWords   
    cmp ebx,1                ; compare EBX and 1
  jle Error                ; jump if Less than or equal  (<=)

    mov edx, OFFSET msg2a     ; "Fibonacci Series is "
    call WriteString 
    mov edx, OFFSET msg2b        
    call Crlf                ; Writes an end-of-line sequence to the console window.

    mov eax,dPrevious
    call WriteDec            ; Display an unsigned 32-bit integer value
                             ; in EAX in decimal format. 

    call Crlf



    mov ecx,dNumberOfTerms    ; ECX  initialize with Number Of Terms
    sub ecx,2                 ; Exclude First Two Terms

    cmp ecx,0                 ; compare EBX and 0
  je showSum                ; jump if equal  (=)

       L1:
    mov ebx,dPrevious
        add ebx,dCurrent
     mov dNext,ebx
    mov eax,DNext
     cmp ecx,1
         jne ffff
           ;add dSum,eax
    ffff:

       loop L1
   showSum:     

    jmp next
  Error:
    mov edx, OFFSET msg4     ; "Error: Fibonacci Series Contain at least 2 number of terms"
    call WriteString
     cmp eax,1         
    call Crlf
  next:                
call WaitMsg    ; Displays a message and waits for a key to be pressed.
exit            ; The exit statement (indirectly) calls a predefined 
                ; MS-Windows function that halts the program.
main ENDP  ; The ENDP directive marks the end of the main procedure.
END main       ; The END directive marks the last line of the program to be assembled.
```

Comment: If you want to break a string into two, just break it into two. :) Separate `msg2a BYTE...` and `msg2b BYTE...`. Write them out separately, wring the number in between. It's a lot easier and clearer than trying to break it algorithmically.

Comment: so would that be msg2a BYTE "The nth term in Fibonacci Series is ",0

Comment: msg2b BYTe"The th term in Fibonacci Seri is", WRiteSTring?

Comment: also what do I do with the message  mov edx, OFFSET msg2  ?

Comment: `msg2a BYTE "The ", 0`, and `msg2b BYTE "th term in Fibonacci Series is ", 0`. Write out `msg2a`, then write out your integer, then write out `msg2b`. If you want to get really fancy, you can check if your number ends in 1 or 2 and make sure it says, `st` or `nd` instead of `th`, but that's beyond the scope of this specific exercise.

Comment: Thanks so what will happen to the msg2 after mov edx, OFFSET?

Comment: If you have `msg2a` and `msg2b`, then you don't need `msg2` any more. `mov edx, OFFSET msg2a`, `call WriteString`, then write out your number, then, `mov edx, OFFSET msg2b`, `call WriteString`, `call Crlf`.

Comment: Hey I just edited my code, you can please check it out? I put msg2 a and b in

Comment: also what do you mean write out your integer, or ends it st or nd?

Comment: It means you need to write out whatever `n` is. For example, `The 4th term in the FIbonacci Series is ...". You need to write out the 4 after you write out `msg2a` and before you write out `msg2b`. I leave that as an exercise. You should be able to figure it out. :) By `st` or `nd` I meant if you are writing out the 2nd number, it's going to say, `The 2th term in the Fibonacci Series..` instead of `...the 2nd term...`. That takes a little more work to make perfect.

Comment: Thank you so much can I accept your asnwer? also would you know any way to change the formula in this code? I want change it from fibonacci to f(n-2)/2 + f(n-1) * 2

Comment: I posted an answer which you can accept if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split your message, make it into two data items:

```
msg2a BYTE "The ", 0
msg2b BYTE "th term in Fibonacci Series is ", 0
```

Then in the code:

```
mov edx, OFFSET msg2a     ; "Fibonacci Series is "
call WriteString 
; ...
; Code here to write out the value of `n`
; ...
mov edx, OFFSET msg2b        
call Crlf
```

This won't be so elegant if `n` is 1 or 2 because it will say, `1th` or `2th`. I will leave it as an exercise to fix that if you want to. You can break your message up further for that if needed. For example:

```
msg2a BYTE "The ", 0
msg2b BYTE "st", 0
msg2c BYTE "nd", 0
msg2d BYTE " term in Fibonacci Series is ", 0
```

And adjust according to the value of `n`.

As far as modifying the formula from `f(n-1) + f(n-2)` to `f(n-1)*2 + f(n-2)/2`, locate where where `f(n-1)` and `f(n-2)` are determined and use the fact that `*2` is the same as a single bit shift left, and `/2` is the same as a single bit shift right. It's left as another exercise. If you look things up, it should be quite simple. :)

Comment: @Steveknisely  Yes. And so do you I think.

Comment: also I have another question sir, do I still need to delete showSum:   jmp before the error? since I deleted the showsum of the code, do I still need that part in there?